# FK Constraint for two tables with same PK column

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

I have two tables "customer" and "services". both columns have the same column customer_id as PK. I left joined the tables using customer_id. Can I add a constraint for a customer FK on services referencing services PK customer_id (which is also a PK for the table customer)? If yes, is that even necessary so there is referential integrity?

Comment: the question is, why is services using customer_id as pk. is that a 1:1 relationship?

Comment: Yes 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Did you try to create an FK?

Comment: Yes, to clarify a bit more, I have the main table customer with customer_id  as PK, the new added table services also has customer_id and is the same column with the same number of unique clients. I wanted a FK on services.customer_id but I thought i needed to have services.customer_id as a PK for the FK to work. I tried it and it ran without errors but was wondering if that is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, you should have referential integrity.

Comment: @aaa.mtz: your explanation in the comment should be part of the question. Ideally include the SQL statements you have used.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.